# calculate string (number) between two "</span>", and replace it with half the value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html:

```
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₪</span>
  13.9
</span>
```

I want to show half the price, e.g. half of 13.9 in this case (the code appears many times in the page, each time a different amount).

I tried this for capturing the string within the quote marks:

```
var str = $(".tax-product_cat.term-185 .woocommerce-Price-amount").html();
var newStr = str.split("</span>")[1].split("</span>")[0];
var halfprice = parseInt(newStr, 10) / 2;
$(".tax-product_cat.term-185 .woocommerce-Price-amount").html("<span class='woocommerce-Price-amount amount'><span class='woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol'>₪</span>"+halfprice+"</span>");
```

but didn't really work.

any ideas?
thanks!

Comment: Can you edit HTML? Can you pre-process HTML and put additional data using e.g. PHP?

Comment: It'd make life considerably easier if you can wrap the price (decimal value) in another span

Comment: @Justinas unfortunately not, the html is generated automatically from the products price...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the symbol string, use jQuery [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method, and use it as a split delimiter in the the whole text content of the root span.

```js
$(".woocommerce-Price-amount").each(function(){
  var symbol = $(this).find(".woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol").text();
  var half = $(this).text().split(symbol)[1] / 2;
  console.log(half);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₪</span> 13.9
</span>

<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₪</span> 13.9
</span>

<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₪</span> 13.9
</span>
```

Comment: I like the use of the inner `.find()` to find the currency symbol, rather than just assume it's what's posted above.

Comment: I used it like this:
`$(".tax-product_cat.term-185 .idoslideritem .woocommerce-Price-amount").each(function(){
  var symbol = $(this).find(".woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol").text();
  var half = $(this).text().split(symbol)[1] / 2;
  $(this).html("<span class='woocommerce-Price-amount amount'><span class='woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol'>₪</span>"+half+"</span>");
});`

Answer (score 2):

Get the text element after the `woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol`, and manipulate its `textContent`.  Unfortunately, you can't use `':last-child` selectors for text nodes so this is the next best approach.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol')

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  const textNode = elements[i].nextSibling
  textNode.textContent = parseFloat(textNode.textContent) / 2
}
```

```html
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₪</span> 13.9
</span>

<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₪</span> 14.9
</span>

<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">₪</span> 15.9
</span>
```